# Are there any decent spam filters for Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

Are there any other spam filters that work as well as Gmails' filter?

Since we don't use Gmail for our mail I would prefer something that plugs into Outlook.

I'm not the sys admin, so I don't have access to the mail server itself.

---

After everyone gave their answer  I stumbled upon [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/69972/spam-is-killing-me-can-i-use-gmail-as-a-spam-filter). Unintentionally, it gives me some nice solutions.

Comment: to answer your question we would need: what email program do you use (MUA - mail user agent), how is your email delivered to your (MTA - mail transfer agent)? are you in control of that? do you have to handle your spam on the server side (before it reaches your inbox) or do you have to fish out spam from your inbox? etc etc...

Comment: We use outlook. I have total control. I was hopeing to simply forward all received mail to [~gmail] and back. Where, [~gmail] would magically make all the spam disappear.

Comment: total control means "i see the mails arriving at my email-server and i control the programm that talks to outlook via pop/imap"?

Comment: I use discretion when giving out my e-mail address.  That tends to work better than any spam filter.

Comment: Haha, funny Iszi. We arnt talking about personal email addresses here.

Comment: Total control meaning I dont know how to do that stuff but I dont have anyone telling me I cant do that.

Comment: @Oak Is this for one person or for a company?

Comment: A small company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can address this problem via:

- when email arrives at your (the company's) email-server (exim, postfix, qmail, exchange) you can apply something like spamassasin, clamav(antivirus) or other server related spam filter to detect spam and either drop it, mark it spam, deliver it to a special folder. bonus: since you see all email in one place you can learn about the spam and train the filter accordingly.
- when email arrives at each user (aka "the user opens outlook / thunderbird") you can install something like spambayes to detect spam when it hits the user. that spamfilter will be as good as the user trains it. if the user is dumb, bad results but you are off the hook since you delivered ALL mails and you wont have any trouble explaining why "that one important email from dude xyz is not in my inbox??". i personally like the spamefilter of 'thunderbird3'  (offers gmail similar email search (or 'xobni').

Answer (score 3):

Spamassassin for Outlook (as a plugin) seems to be an inactive project:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/saoutlook/

There's a plugin for Outlook that works on a per-user basis to learn what is and what is not spam - but it requires some manual training:

http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/

If you want to host your own anti-spam and antivirus mail filter for multiple users, in house, I can strongly recommend an Open Source app called MailScanner, which runs on a Linux-based server. MailScanner wraps SpamAssassin, ClamAV, and a number of other optional (free and non-free) antivirus and anti-spam tools around an MTA ('mail server'). The learning curve can be a bit steep if you have no Linux experience but the mailing list members are a great bunch and are very helpful.

http://www.mailscanner.info/

Answer (score 1):

Try SpamAssassin. It works acceptably out of the box. Also, dayly updates helps alot. With a user-initiated learning (like google's "Report spam") SA shows very good results in a week.